# SQL Sum and Count JOIN Multiple tables

Tags: sql, count, sum, multiple-tables

Please help, I want to merge this two query

I have 3 Tables (places,ratings,places_image)

**places**

- id
- name
- description

**ratings**

- id
- rating
- place_id
- user_id

**places_image**

- id
- place_id
- image

These are the 2 queries:

```
SELECT places.*, SUM(rating) AS total_rating,COUNT(ratings.user_id) AS total_user FROM ratings, places WHERE ratings.place_id = places.id GROUP BY places.id
SELECT places.*, places_images.image FROM places, places_images WHERE places.id = places_images.place_id GROUP BY places.id
```

Query 1
[image]

Query 2
[image]

I tried to do this query but it give **duplicate data** for the **aggregate** function

```
SELECT places.id, places.name, places.description, places_images.image ,SUM(rating) AS total_rating,COUNT(ratings.user_id) AS total_user FROM places_images JOIN places ON places_images.place_id = places.id JOIN ratings ON ratings.place_id = places.id GROUP BY places.id
```

Query 3
[image]

How can i combine it ?

Comment: Your second query is malformed.  The `GROUP BY` columns are not consistent with the unaggregated `SELECT` columns.  The question is unclear.  You should provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what *you* mean by "combine it".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the only thing i need is to subquery it

```
select a.*, d.image, b.totalRating, c.totalUser from places a, ( select place_id, sum(rating) AS totalRating from ratings group by place_id ) b, ( select place_id, count(id) AS totalUser from ratings group by place_id ) c, places_images d where c.place_id = a.id and b.place_id = a.id and d.place_id = a.id GROUP BY a.id
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxy87.png)

Thank you very much, GBU

Answer (score -1):

You need to use 2 Inner Join on the place_id and user_id

It'll be something like

```
SELECT SUM(r.rating) AS total_ratings, COUNT(r.user_id) AS total_users
FROM ratings r 
INNER JOIN places p ON p.id = r.user_id 
INNER JOIN places_image pi ON pi.place_id = r.place_id    
GROUP BY r.id
```

Comment: Thanks but still didnt get the result, it show same sum and count more than once

Comment: I'll have to take a look at home. My current location has the pictures blocked so I can see them. Maybe you can nest my previous answer in another select statement and use the DISTINCT keyword. Not sure how advanced you are but you should be able to look up nested queries and distinct.

Comment: "SQL Inner Join clause is the same as Join clause and works the same way if we don't specify the type (INNER) while using the Join clause."